# hyperlink click: old url gets concatenated to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am converting url `http://localhost:85/html/Home.php?v=somevalue&t=somevalue` to `http://localhost:85/html/Home/v/somevalue/t/somevalue` using following code in htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /html/

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Home\.php\?v=([^\s&]+)&t=([^\s&]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ Home/v/%1/t/%2? [R=302,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^Home/v/([^/]+)/t/([^/]+)?$ Home.php?v=$1&t$2 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

This code works properly first time. But when I click another hyperlink having href `/html/Home.php?v=somevalue2&t=somevalue2` it doesn't work.

Instead of passing new parameters, url gets concatenated as follows `/html/Home/v/somevalue/t/html/Home.php?v=somevalue2`.

Am I missing something? I just want to replace query string by parameters in url.